# External-secrets not able to access the AWS STS from a private cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-secrets-manager

from the last couple of days, I have been trying to figure a way to read the Secrets from AWS secret manager from my private EKS cluster with FARGATE.

For doing so I have attempted to use an open-source tool
https://github.com/external-secrets/external-secrets
but I couldn't make it work with the private cluster.

I can read the passwords in my local by running the source-code of the above-link when I am connected to internet. But when I deploy the pod to AWS private cluster it always gives an timeout error as shown in the below code snippets.

```
vel":"error","ts":1637220916.9525745,"logger":"controllers.ExternalSecret","msg":"could not reconcile ExternalSecret. Please check!!!","ExternalSecret":"commons/example","SecretStore":"commons/secretstore-sample","error":"could not get secret data from provider: key \"myTestSecret/random\" from ExternalSecret \"example\": WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://sts.amazonaws.com/\": dial tcp 209.54.180.124:443: i/o timeout","stacktrace":"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\t/home/cloudberry/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.9.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:298\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\t/home/cloudberry/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.9.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:253\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\t/home/cloudberry/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.9.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:214"}
```

I have been struggling to make it work, I have also attempted to change the source-code by changing the URLs in the code as I found it hard-coded at one place but still the error doesn't go away.

Any hints of how to make external-secrets work in a private cluster will be very much helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already create a role with a policy to access secret manager for external-secrets? Have you followed steps to provide the external-secrets pod with that role? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: I have tried creating service-account and in that approach only I am getting this error. Also attempted the env variable approach but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days I finally manage to resolve the issue by creating my custom Code in Java.

What I did ?

1. Created a IAM profile and role in AWS that can access Secret Manager.
2. Created a service-account in K8 using which my Pod can access the secret-manager. Service-account can hold IAM role details (created in step-1).
3. Using AWS SDK and sample code fetched the secrets from secret manager.
4. Used the below gradle dependency to create K8 secrets:

   implementation 'io.fabric8:kubernetes-client:5.10.1'

Git repo for step 3 Git reference is : https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md